# Need proper delimiter of this string

Tags: php, preg-match, delimiter, modifier

Can you someone please tell me how to correctly add delimiter in this string:

```
  if (!preg_match ('' . '\\/\\/' . $host, $referer))
```

Many thanks in advance, I've tried everything (/ and @ ) but it does not works for me! :(

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @BVengerov I am getting PHP Warning Error "Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash" - anything what I tried to add, like / or @ as delimiter it still not works for me.

Comment: Why do you need to use `preg_match`? `$host` probably isn't a regular expression, so just do an ordinary string search with `strstr()`.

Comment: @Barmar Basically  I have changed this from ereg() to preg_match() now, because ereg() is DEPRECATED in PHP 5.3.0 so I now have again change it from preg_match() to strstr() are you sure it will work? Need more answers... so, this string can't be proprely delimited with / or @ etc... ?

Answer (score 0):

The last symbol in your regex is the last symbol of `$host` value, so basically it's just invalid regex.

This should work: `preg_match ("#//$host#", $referer);`, but you probably can use simple string search, as mentioned in comments.

EDIT:

Example for `strstr`:

`if(strstr($referer, $host) === false)`

Comment: Can you please give me a code also for simple string, sorry but I have no idea how to do with simple string search, as mentioned in comments? Many thanks in advance, I will test this code also!

Comment: I use if (!preg_match("#//$host#", $referer)); and PHP error is gone, I think that would be fine. Thank you so much  anyway  BVengerov.

Answer (score 0):

Unless `$host` contains regular expression pattern characters, you should be able to change that to:

```
if(!strstr($referer, '//' . $host))
```

But if it's actually a regular expression, you can use any character that you don't expect to appear in `$host` as the delimiter, for instance `#` is an unlikely host character.

```
if (!preg_match("#//$host#", $referer));
```

Since you're not using `/` as the delimiter, you don't need to escape those characters.

Comment: I use the second code, for more safety, thank you Barmar again!